# Google Drive API in Python (What is the authorization code?)

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

the code was working but I had to revoke the temporary token because my app was still in testing, but now it shows on console:
"Enter the authorization code:" But What is the authorization code??

```
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret_xxxxxxx.json'
API_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly',]

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorization code is the response from the authorization as part of the fist step in the authorization process.

When your application runs you should ask the user to navigate to a web site where they will be shown the consent screen.

[image]

When the user consents to the request for authorization.  Then a new browser window will open and the authorization code will appear in the url of the browser.

This code is then used by your application to exchange for an access token which will give your application access to request data from the users account.

I think that you should have a look at the official google drive sample.  [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) authorizaotn code you will find here will work better then what you have now.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: hummm ok thanks, Quickstart running,  the new new browser opeened and "The authentication flow has completed. You may close this window". but in my app still it shows on console: "Enter the authorization code:

Comment: See the client library handles all the authorization for you.  You need not worry about the authorization code.